# Can I connect two vpc's with one site to site vpn in same region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn, vpc-peering

I currently have one site to site vpn connected to one vpc.

I want to add a vpc here(It's the same region),

but I want to connect the on-premise network connected through site to site vpn through site to site vpn without a separate vpn.

I think you can connect to the vpc connected to the vpn with vpc peering.

Is this possible or is there another way??

[expected architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikv13.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way.

There is only a way to attach site to site vpn by vpc.

You cannot connect a vpc to a vpn that is vpc peering because the vpc is connected through vpn on one side.